# Spring Boot redirect after successfull Login

Tags: java, spring, security, redirect, spring-boot

I am trying to redirect to a deeper folder structure after success login.

This inside my WebSecurityConfig:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER").anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/logon")
                    .usernameParameter("personContactEmail").passwordParameter("personRegPwd")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/successauth", true) 
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
            .csrf();
}
```

And this inside the /successauth Request mapping:

```
    @RequestMapping("/successauth")
public void afterLogon(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    authentication = authenticationFacade.getAuthentication();

    if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
        RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, "/user/home");
    }
}
```

It does not want to redirect to /user/home.
This is the request mapping for /user/home:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String userHome(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    return "/user/home";
}
```

Comment: According to `.antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER").anyRequest().permitAll()` you should have access to `/user/home` as *USER*. After login what role you get in _authentication_ ?

Comment: I get role as USER. That is not the problem.
In my WebSecurityConfig I have changed to this:
.defaultSuccessUrl("/user/home", true)

It still does not work.
But when I change to .defaultSuccessUrl("/users/home", true)
and change the RequestMapping of my controller to also "/users/home" and in the RequestMapping return value set "/user/home" it goes to the correct page.

But doing this, it bypasses all security because /users is not part of the WebSecurityConfig.

Answer (score 0):

JUst define this in your `configure` method the

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/user/home", true)
```

to redirect user to home after login

UPDATE:

You can define custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler
http://javapointers.com/tutorial/spring-custom-authenticationsuccesshandler-example-2/

to redirect user. Also try to set `csrf().disabled()` in your config

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but getting "White Label Error" page. Not sure what else I am doing wrong, also my reason for going to a different controller first is because I want to redirect the user to different path based on ROLE.
ROLE_USER - /user/home
ROLE_ADMM - /admin/home
etc
etc

Comment: This is interesting, if I change to .defaultSuccessUrl("/users/home", true) and also change the RequestMapping to "/users/home" but keep hte return of the RequestMapping as "/user/home", it works. But by doing to, I completely remove the security from the user folder.

Comment: I have tried csrf().disable() and it still does not work.

In my WebSecurityConfig I have changed to this:
.defaultSuccessUrl("/user/home", true)

It still does not work.
But when I change to .defaultSuccessUrl("/users/home", true)
and change the RequestMapping of my controller to also "/users/home" and in the RequestMapping return value set "/user/home" it goes to the correct page.

But doing this, it bypasses all security because /users is not part of the WebSecurityConfig.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad, I think!

I defined my userRoles List as type String:

```
private List<String> userRoles;
```

Thus when accessing it, I had only the String value of the Object reference and not the Object itself. The Collection of GrantedAuthority was only String values and thus I think my authentication did not work and thus could not redirect.

After changing to List to UserRoles entity Object:

```
private List<UserRoles> userRoles;
```

Everything just fell in place and worked perfectly.
Thanks to all for answering.